# How to properly check is real number mask in maskedtextbox completed or not?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, maskedtextbox

Let's say there is a MaskedTextBox which accepts real numbers in **0.00** - **99.99** range. At least one digit in integral part is required, digits in decimal part are optional.

So I can set Mask to **90.99** and after that rely on MaskedTextBox.MaskCompleted property. But if user enters for example **1_.00** then **MaskedTextBox.MaskCompleted=false**.

I can set Mask to **09.99**, but again if user enters for example **_1.00** then **MaskedTextBox.MaskCompleted=false**.

So is there a way to set up mask to have MaskedTextBox.MaskCompleted working properly.

Or the only way is directly reading and analyzing **MaskedTextBox.Text** in my code?

Comment: Question Title is messed up!

Comment: Thought a lot about correct title. Do you think there is a better one?

Comment: Well, `1_.00` *is* a messed up number. It has a gap.

Comment: But according to requirements of my software - it's correct one. Symbol . is a maskedtextbox literal and is not supposed to be entered by user.